# return polygon nearest to a point using terra in R

Tags: r, raster, terra

I am doing a point in polygon analysis

```
library(terra)
library(rnaturalearth)
  
crdref <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

lonlat<- structure(c(-123.115684, -81.391114, -74.026122, -122.629252, 
                      -159.34901, 7.76101, 48.080979, 31.159987, 40.621058, 47.50331, 
                       21.978049, 36.90086), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), 
                      .Dimnames = list(NULL,c("longitude", "latitude")))

pts <- vect(lonlat, crs = crdref)
world_shp <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries()
world_shp <- terra::vect(world_shp, crs = crdref)
world_shp <- terra::project(world_shp, crdref)

plot(world_shp)
points(pts, col = "red", pch = 20)
```

[image]

All these points lie on the edges of polygon and hence when I try to extract the the polygon under which each point lies, I get an NA

```
e <- terra::extract(world_shp, pts) 
e$sovereignt
NA
```

Is there any way I can return the nearest polygon for each point using the `terra` package

Comment: I'm getting an error on `> pts <- vect(lonlat, crs = crdref)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'vect': object 'lonlat' not found`

Comment: Apologies. I have edited the mistake in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `st_join` from the `sf` package:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)

devtools::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires")
library(rnaturalearthhires)


# create points dataframe
points <- tibble(longitude = c(123.115684, -81.391114, -74.026122, -122.629252,
                               -159.34901, 7.76101),
                 latitude = c(48.080979, 31.159987, 40.621058, 47.50331,
                              21.978049, 36.90086)) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())

# convert to spatial
points <- points %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"),
           crs = 4326)

# load Natural Earth data
world_shp <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf",
                                         scale = "large")


# Plot points on top of map (just for fun)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world_shp) +
  geom_sf(data = points, color = "red", size = 2)


# check that the two objects have the same CRS
st_crs(points) == st_crs(world_shp)


# locate for each point the nearest polygon
nearest_polygon <- st_join(points, world_shp,
                           join = st_nearest_feature)

nearest_polygon
```

Comment: Please try to plot the result of `world_shp` after `st_make_valid`.

Comment: Dear lord. Those polygons were definitely very invalid

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to @Mossa's comment. It was an error with the `ne_countries()` function which can be fixed by specifying `returnclass` and `scale`. This, in turn, requires the `rnaturalearthhires` package to be installed

Comment: okay thanks. I have done similar solution earlier but wanted to check if there's anything in the `terra` package that can be used. But thanks. I will accept the answer after a while

Comment: The `terra` package is mostly for raster data. You tried to treat the polygons as raster data (with `extract`). I see no reason why you wouldn't use an `sf` approach

Comment: I love this, upvoted answer; Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `terra::nearest`

Example data

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
pts <- matrix(c(5.812,6.577,5.864,50.126,49.774,49.488), ncol=2)
pts <- vect(pts, crs = crs(w))
```

Solution

```
pv = as.points(v)
n = nearest(pts, pv)

i = pv$NAME_2[n$to_id]
i
#[1] "Clervaux"         "Echternach"       "Esch-sur-Alzette"
```

Illustration

```
plot(v, border="gray", lwd=3)
text(v, "NAME_2", cex=.6)
points(pts)
lines(pts, n, col="blue", lwd=3)
text(pts, i, cex=.6, col="red", halo=TRUE, adj=c(.5,1.5))
```

[image]

For the example above, you could also do

```
n = nearest(pts, v)
```

But in most cases you would want the distance to the border, not the centroids and do

```
n = nearest(pts, v, centroids=FALSE)
```

The current version returns the wrong IDs (for the nodes, not the polygons) so that cannot be used